# Can't download javascript or css files anymore

Tags: browser, download

Whenever I click on the download link it just shows me a page of code. I tried in IE8, IE9, FireFox, Chrome, Safari, Opera... In all of them it does this. Why?

[image: Example: Downloading jQuery-1.8.3.js from jquery.com]

Comment: What *download* link? Is it a single web site that's affected? Have you tried logging out or restarting? Does it happen on another computer as well?

Comment: @DanielBeck It's like that with every .js or .css file on no-matter what website I'm on. I tried resetting to default settings, I tried reinstalling them all - nothing helps :s

Comment: So you're using SU right now essentially with JS and CSS disabled?

Comment: I want to make sure I understand. If you click on a link to a JavaScript or CSS file (or enter the address of a JavaScript or CSS file in the address box), all of your browsers show the text of the file. But you want your browsers to show a download prompt instead? If so, I know how to change this in Opera. I (or someone else) might need to research the other browsers.

Comment: This is old, but I have same thing here. Chrome removes css files upon download.

Answer (score 3):

Why is this a problem? This is the default behavior of most browsers. If you need a copy of the .js or .css file, just go to `File -> Save as...` or the equivalent in your browser.

Comment: +1 , you might also encounter this issue with pdf files, current browsers are capable of rendering a lot of different filetypes

Answer (score 0):

You can change how Opera handles JavaScript and CSS files that you navigate to directly using these steps:

1. Go to the Settings (or Tools) menu, Preferences command, Advanced tab, Downloads category.
2. Uncheck "Hide file types opened with Opera".
3. In the Quick find box, type `text/`
4. Select the item you want to edit.
   On my computer I see `text/css` is for CSS files and `text/javascript` and `text/ecmascript` are for JavaScript files.
5. Click Edit. Choose "Show download dialog" or whatever other option you want Opera to do.

[image: Opera's MIME type list]

[image: Opera's file type actions]

## About MIME types

When you request a file from a web server, the server sends a MIME type header that indicates the type of the file. (When you request a file from an FTP server, there is no MIME type sent, so browsers use the file extension to tell what type the file is.) Typically a browser uses the MIME type to decide how to handle the file. If there's no MIME type available, it uses the file extension.

Opera lets you see all of the MIME types and extensions it knows about and lets you modify how it handles them. Other browsers often show simpler lists.

For the `text/` MIME types, if a browser doesn't have a setting for the specific MIME type (like `text/css` or `text/javascript`) it will typically just display the text in the browser window because the `text/` prefix indicates the file is text-based. Resetting your browser to default settings will probably restore this kind of behavior.

## Checking the MIME type

If you change the MIME type action, but the browser's action doesn't change, the web server may be sending a different MIME type then expected. If the browser is displaying the file in the browser window, you can check the MIME type as follows:

- In Opera, press F4, go to the Info panel, and look at the MIME type.
- In Firefox, right-click in the window, choose View Page Info, go to the General tab, and look at the Type.

If the MIME type looks like a correct alternative you weren't aware of, you can modify or add it in Opera's file type list.

If the MIME type is wrong or not specific enough (for example, if `text/plain` is used but `text/javascript` would be better), consider asking the website administrator to set the server to send a more appropriate MIME type.